# Linq Order by is not displaying Data when data passed through jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

in linq query i had given order by id.it is giving according to that .but iam showing data through jquery where it is coming in alphabetical order.

```
var datatableVariable = $('#tblImageUpload').DataTable({
                  data: data,
                 
                  columns: [
                                               
                                                { 'data': 'MemberDescription'},
                                                { 'data': 'EmpPhoto',
                                                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                                        var imgsrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
                                                        return '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + imgsrc + '" height="100px" width="100px">';
                                                    }
                                                },        
                                                {

                                                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                                                        return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-danger btndelete" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></span>'

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
```

My linq query is:

```
var imagesUploaded = (from al in tbl.Image.Where(a => (a.CreatedBy == empName))
                              orderby al.CreatedDate descending
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = al.Id,
                                  MemberDescription = al.MemberDescription,
                                  ImagePath = al.ImagePath,
                                  EmpPhoto = al.EmpPhoto,
                              }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: You've excluded all the relevant information - what's your LINQ query?

Comment: i updated my linq query

Comment: Try adding the `orderby` after the select; also a step-by-step debug will show you of the linq query is returning the expected list.

Comment: Consider sticking with one syntax or the other. The mix of query syntax and method syntax just makes it harder to read. Check the data; since you do not include the `CreatedDate` in the output, I'm not sure how you can be sure that sorting by that field also coincidentally made it sorted alphabetically. As it is, there is simply not enough information to answer this question completely.

Comment: linq  is giving result as expected.it is working fine only.but when it goes to jquery the result on sceen is not coming in order

Comment: CreatedDate is record created date in table i need to get the data order by createdDate.i no need to show any where that column so no meaning to show in select query

Comment: Ok, so you're checking your linq is correct, then you're asserting that the output is not correct - so what happens in between?   Is `imagesUploaded` correct (*after* the linq)?  What do you do wit `imagesUpload` to return it?  What is being transferred in the network tab of the browser?  Is `data` correct (*before* .DataTable())?   In your linq, what's `al`?  Is `b` used?

Comment: imagedUploaded data is correct.so it will be having json data. that i am passing to jQuery. On jquery success the data what  i am getting also correct .but while displaying in screen the order is not correct. b is my typo mistake it is al .it is to get the columns from query

Comment: As far as I know datatables.net jquery plugin configured with ajax is expecting a response in a different format. Not just an array of items, but an actual object that includes fields containing 1. the total number of records 2. the page ...

Comment: So how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var datatableVariable = $('#tblImageUpload').DataTable({
              data: data,
             "order": [],
              columns: [
                                           
                                            { 'data': 'MemberDescription'},
                                            { 'data': 'EmpPhoto',
                                                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                                    var imgsrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
                                                    return '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + imgsrc + '" height="100px" width="100px">';
                                                }
                                            },        
                                            {

                                                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                                                    return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-danger btndelete" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></span>'

                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
```

Adding order in code solved my issue